# Webservice not returning correct date format

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I am calling a webservice to get date . Date returned to to the UI is in format **1530158400000** but i need it in **"2018-06-12"** how can i do this. My UI is angular js and the webservice that returns the response object( out DTO)has "protected Date trdDate" . My hibernate query criteria returns correct format  **"2018-06-12"** response object in the web-service also has correct format. But when i check the response in UI it is**1530158400000**

Comment: WHERE IS YOUR CODE??

Comment: Is WebService response SOAP or JSON? anyway there must be transformation defined for Date type in WebService, because your response is milliseconds.

Comment: It is a json response

Comment: @OleV.V. didn't notice caps lock key on.. Sorry if it seems rude..!! that was nt my intention..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired date format by following below steps -

1. create an application.properties or if you already have then update it with:

   spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps:false
2. annotate date field of your DTO with:

   @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
   protected Date trdDate

> Output: "2018-06-08T18:35:53.153+0000"

Note: you can keep the pattern according to your expected date format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your response is the date in milliseconds then

```
var d=new Date(response).toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

should be the answer you want, d the date you want